# Angularjs error using with C# ASP .net CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs

Hi I am currently playing around with Angularjs in a ASP.NET Core Web Application.I am new to Angularjs and want to get the standard of using it in ASP.NET correct. My app.js looks like the following

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('employeeapp', ['EmployeeService']);
})();

My controller.js looks like 

(function () {
    'use strict';
    employeeapp.controller('employeeController', function ($scope, EmployeeService) {

        EmployeeService.getEmployees()
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.employees = response.data;
            console.log($scope.employees);
        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    })
})();
```

and my factory.js looks like

```
(function () {
    'use strict';


    var EmployeeService = {};
    EmployeeService.getEmployees = function () {
        return $http.get('/Home/GetDetails');
    };
    return EmployeeService;
})();
```

I am using grunt and it creates a apps.js file in my wwwroot/lib folder which looks like

```
!function(){"use strict";angular.module("employeeapp",["EmployeeService"])}(),function(){"use strict";employeeapp.controller("employeeController",function(a,b){b.getEmployees().then(function(b){a.employees=b.data,console.log(a.employees)},function(a){console.log(a)})})}(),function(){"use strict";var a={};return a.getEmployees=function(){return $http.get("/Home/GetDetails")},a}();
```

My view looks like the following

```
<html ng-app="employeeapp">
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}
<head>
</head>
<body ng-controller="employeeController">

    <table style="width: 99%; background-color:#FFFFFF; border solid 2px #6D7B8D; padding 5px;width 99%;table-layout:fixed;" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">

        <tr style="height: 30px; background-color:#336699 ; color:#FFFFFF ;border: solid 1px #659EC7;">
            <td width="40" align="center"><b>Employee ID</b></td>
            <td width="60" align="center"><b>Employee Code</b></td>
            <td width="100" align="center"><b>Employee First Name</b></td>
            <td width="120" align="center"><b>Employee Last Name</b></td>

        </tr>
        <tbody ng-repeat="details in EmployeeService">
            <tr>

                <td align="center" style="border: solid 1px #659EC7; padding: 5px;table-layout:fixed;">
                    <span style="color:#9F000F">
                        {{details.EmployeeId}}
                    </span>
                </td>

                <td align="center" style="border: solid 1px #659EC7; padding: 5px;table-layout:fixed;">
                    <span style="color:#9F000F">
                        {{details.EmployeeCode}}
                    </span>
                </td>

                <td valign="top" style="border: solid 1px #659EC7; padding: 5px;table-layout:fixed;">
                    <span style="color:#9F000F">
                        {{details.FirstName}}
                    </span>
                </td>

                <td valign="top" style="border: solid 1px #659EC7; padding: 5px;table-layout:fixed;">
                    <span style="color:#9F000F">
                        {{details.LastName}}
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

When running i am getting the following error.

```
app.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: employeeapp is not defined
    at app.js:1
    at app.js:1
angular.js:4587 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module employeeapp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module EmployeeService due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'EmployeeService' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/nomod?p0=EmployeeService
    at http://localhost:24842/lib/angular/angular.js:68:12
    at http://localhost:24842/lib/angular/angular.js:2070:17
    at ensure (http://localhost:24842/lib/angular/angular.js:1994:38)
    at module (http://localhost:24842/lib/angular/angular.js:2068:14)
    at http://localhost:24842/lib/angular/angular.js:4564:22
    at forEach (http://localhost:24842/lib/angular/angular.js:322:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:24842/lib/angular/angular.js:4548:5)
    at http://localhost:24842/lib/angular/angular.js:4565:40
    at forEach (http://localhost:24842/lib/angular/angular.js:322:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:24842/lib/angular/angular.js:4548:5)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/modulerr?
```

Hoping someone can help me with this.

Thanks
Ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `employeeapp` variable defined, so `employeeapp.controller` will not work.

Change it to `angular.module("employeeapp").controller` and the first error should disappear.

Regarding the second error, you are using `EmployeeService` both as a module:

```
angular.module('employeeapp', ['EmployeeService']);
```

And as a service:

```
employeeapp.controller('employeeController', function ($scope, EmployeeService)
```

But you haven't registered it as neither.

Change to the following to not depend on it as a module:

```
angular.module('employeeapp', []);
```

And register it as a service/factory:

```
angular.module("employeeapp").factory('EmployeeService', function($http) {
  var EmployeeService = {};
  EmployeeService.getEmployees = function() {
    return $http.get('/Home/GetDetails');
  };
  return EmployeeService;
});
```

To make it work after minification:

```
employeeapp.controller('employeeController', ['$scope', 'EmployeeService', function($scope, EmployeeService) {

  EmployeeService.getEmployees()
    .then(function(response) {
      $scope.employees = response.data;
      console.log($scope.employees);
    }, function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
}]);
```

And:

```
angular.module("employeeapp").factory('EmployeeService', ['$http', function($http) {
  var EmployeeService = {};
  EmployeeService.getEmployees = function() {
    return $http.get('/Home/GetDetails');
  };
  return EmployeeService;
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems to fixed my first probem. Now it is throwing this error.

Comment: @RyanRichard Sorry, I missed the second error when answering. Will update soon.

Comment: @RyanRichard Updated.

Comment: Thanks i made the changes and get this angular.js:13550 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: aProvider <- a <- employeeController

Comment: That's because your code isn't minification protected. Will update again.

Comment: @RyanRichard Updated.

Comment: thanks so much for your. I think im almost there. The error has changed to angular.js:13550 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: EmployeeServiceProvider <- EmployeeService <- employeeController.

Comment: @RyanRichard My bad, forgot to give the factory a name, first argument should be a string like this: `factory('EmployeeService', function () ...`. Updated.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks all is working. Hoping to get much better at this.